ImportError: cannot import name 'deprecated' from 'typing_extensions' with llama_index library
My python version is 3.7.16, and typing-extensions version is 4.7.1. I get the error on running the code below specifically the line importing the llama_index library. Packages are installed with pip. I ran it in Jupyter notebook in vscode.
from llama_index.graph_stores.neo4j import Neo4jPGStore

graph_store = Neo4jPGStore(
    username=os.getenv("NEO4J_USERNAME"),
    password=os.getenv("NEO4J_PASSWORD"),
    url=os.getenv("NEO4J_URI"),
    refresh_schema=False
)

I have tried reinstalling the libraries and using conda environment, all in vain. Error log:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_17914/1908928590.py in <module>
----> 1 from llama_index.graph_stores.neo4j import Neo4jPGStore
      2 
      3 
      4 graph_store = Neo4jPGStore(
      5   username=os.getenv("NEO4J_USERNAME"),

~/miniconda3/envs/thesis/lib/python3.7/site-packages/llama_index/__init__.py in <module>
     13 # embeddings
     14 from llama_index.embeddings.langchain import LangchainEmbedding
---> 15 from llama_index.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbedding
     16 
     17 # structured

~/miniconda3/envs/thesis/lib/python3.7/site-packages/llama_index/embeddings/openai.py in <module>
      4 from typing import Any, List, Optional
      5 
----> 6 import openai
      7 from tenacity import retry, stop_after_attempt, wait_random_exponential
      8 

~/miniconda3/envs/thesis/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openai/__init__.py in <module>
      9 from ._types import NOT_GIVEN, NoneType, NotGiven, Transport, ProxiesTypes
     10 from ._utils import file_from_path
---> 11 from ._client import Client, OpenAI, Stream, Timeout, Transport, AsyncClient, AsyncOpenAI, AsyncStream, RequestOptions
     12 from ._models import BaseModel
     13 from ._version import __title__, __version__

~/miniconda3/envs/thesis/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openai/_client.py in <module>
      9 import httpx
     10 
---> 11 from . import resources, _exceptions
     12 from ._qs import Querystring
     13 from ._types import (

~/miniconda3/envs/thesis/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openai/resources/__init__.py in <module>
      1 # File generated from our OpenAPI spec by Stainless. See CONTRIBUTING.md for details.
      2 
----> 3 from .beta import (
      4     Beta,
      5     AsyncBeta,

~/miniconda3/envs/thesis/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openai/resources/beta/__init__.py in <module>
      1 # File generated from our OpenAPI spec by Stainless. See CONTRIBUTING.md for details.
      2 
----> 3 from .beta import (
      4     Beta,
      5     AsyncBeta,

~/miniconda3/envs/thesis/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openai/resources/beta/beta.py in <module>
      3 from __future__ import annotations
      4 
----> 5 from .threads import (
      6     Threads,
      7     AsyncThreads,

~/miniconda3/envs/thesis/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openai/resources/beta/threads/__init__.py in <module>
      1 # File generated from our OpenAPI spec by Stainless. See CONTRIBUTING.md for details.
      2 
----> 3 from .runs import (
      4     Runs,
      5     AsyncRuns,

~/miniconda3/envs/thesis/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openai/resources/beta/threads/runs/__init__.py in <module>
      1 # File generated from our OpenAPI spec by Stainless. See CONTRIBUTING.md for details.
      2 
----> 3 from .runs import (
      4     Runs,
      5     AsyncRuns,

~/miniconda3/envs/thesis/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openai/resources/beta/threads/runs/runs.py in <module>
     10 import httpx
     11 
---> 12 from ..... import _legacy_response
     13 from .steps import (
     14     Steps,

~/miniconda3/envs/thesis/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openai/_legacy_response.py in <module>
     18     overload,
     19 )
---> 20 from typing_extensions import Awaitable, ParamSpec, override, deprecated, get_origin
     21 
     22 import anyio

ImportError: cannot import name 'deprecated' from 'typing_extensions' (/home/sanjiv/miniconda3/envs/thesis/lib/python3.7/site-packages/typing_extensions.py)


I guess using a conda environment is the issue. Created a virtual environment instead with the same version of libraries and the error goes away.

It seems like this is an issue with the version of Python you're using. I went to both the PyPI page of typing_extensions and its documentation and it mentions that the library only suports Python 3.8 onwards.
Whilst trying to reproduce the bug, I encountered another problem: I could not pip install llama-index-graph-stores-neo4j due to it not being supported in Python 3.7 either. Installing llama_index worked, however it did also raise a (different) error that also seems related to the python version. It just feels like your best bet is to update your Python version to a more modern one.

According to PyPi, though, typing-extensions 4.7.1 is the last version to support Python 3.7, though.

Still, don't think that's the case for the llama-index family. In fact, I could run import typing_extensions (version 4.7.1) in Python 3.7, but not llama-index-graph-stores-neo4j.

llama_index.graph_stores.neo4j requires Python >=3.8.1 which does not match with your Python version 3.7.You should consider updating your Python interpreter.
